# Recognizing these kanji: a counter with a circle at the top; and "【?】に" (looks like 大 at the bottom)

Tags: kanji, handwriting

[image: weird kanji]

I'm puzzling over these kanji...

[image: Recognize kanji]

And this. Is it 数, right? Then, it might be translated as "several meters"?

Answer (score 11):

1. [第１号]{だいいちごう}
2. [実]{じつ}に
3. [数]{すう}[m]{メートル}ほど
   (Yes, it's "several meters" or "a few meters")